# Issue in SimpleDateFormat in android

Tags: android

I have the code to change time format

```
String date = "13/08/13 05.57 PM";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy hh.mm a");
Date testDate = null;
  try {
       testDate = sdf.parse(date);
      }catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
      }
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

I got the output as

```
 .....Date...13-57-2013 05:57:00 PM
```

instead of  13-08-2013 05:57:00 PM. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Problem with `mm` that should be use for minutes. For months you should use `MM`. Read more about [Date and Time Patterns in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)***

---

Use below code

```
String date = "13/08/13 05.57 PM";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh.mm a");
        Date testDate = null;
          try {
               testDate = sdf.parse(date);
              }catch(Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
              }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 'MM' instead of 'mm' where month is expected. Take a look at [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) for the explanation of the different format characters.